# What does "jumper" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, terminology

I was actually looking into the meaning of the word **run-up** after seeing [this](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/267689/what-does-run-mean-in-this-sentence) question. Well after seeing Michael's comment actually, but yeah.

When I [Googled](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=run-up%20meaning) the word, I got the following result:

> 1. the period preceding a notable event.
>    "a programme aimed at lowering unemployment in the run-up to the next election"
> 2. an act of running briefly to gain momentum before performing a jump in athletics, bowling in cricket, etc.
>    "**high jumper** Steve Smith will use his shortened five-stride run-up"
>
> *...and many more.*

Now I fairly understood which meaning of **run-up** was intended in that question. However, the second entry shows this sentence where the phrase "high jumper" is used. Now I looked into the what the word **jumper** means here, but could not deduce my observations. **Jumper** has following entries in the Sports category meanings on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&sxsrf=ALeKk02hgXJPG23BU2P1qAGuOMFarT-PwA%3A1607187275417&ei=S7vLX5iIGZbe9QOCxIqwBw&q=jumper%20meaning&oq=&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQARgAMgcIIxDqAhAnMgcIIxDqAhAnMgcIIxDqAhAnMgcIIxDqAhAnMgcIIxDqAhAnMgcIIxDqAhAnMgcIIxDqAhAnMgcIIxDqAhAnMgcIIxDqAhAnMgcIIxDqAhAnUABYAGD6kyFoAXACeACAAQCIAQCSAQCYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6sAEKwAEB&sclient=psy-ab):

> 1. a person or animal that jumps.
>    "the horse should be a better jumper this season"
>
>    Basketball - another term for jump shot.

Now I really can't understand which meaning is intended in this context. Steve Smith doesn't jump while batting, I mean that's kind of weird. He isn't playing Basketball either.

Is it referring to the motion of him coming forward to hit the ball, like players do when they hit a six (they come considerably away from the stumps to hit the ball)? Also I would appreciate if someone gave me the word for the above described motion (coming forward to hit the ball in cricket), I believe it has a term.

Comment: The **high jump** is a [sports event](https://www.elite-athletic-performance.com/images/high-jump.jpg). Steve Smith is a high jumper.

Comment: @WeatherVane Ohh I know this game. I have seen it in Olympic events. So is Steve Smith here actually a gymnast or like a person who actually plays this sport of high jump?

Comment: Yes, "high jumper Steve Smith..." is like saying "cricketer Don Bradman..."

Comment: My my, I literally thought it was the Australian Cricketer Steve Smith. Seriously, can't Google have used some other name!

Comment: He is the athlete: "high jumper [Steve Smith](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Smith_(British_high_jumper)) will use his shortened five-stride run-up" is like "cricketer Don Bradman will cut the ball through the slips."

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you so much for this information. My Google search was only yielding results for the Australian cricketer. I wasn't able to lookup hence.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The high jump is an athletic event. The athlete jumps over a horizontal pole.  A "high jumper" is an athlete that competes in the high jump competition.

To jump over the pole, high jumpers run-and-jump. So they have a run-up. Apparently, Steve Smith shortened his run-up to five strides.
Here is a video of Steve Smith jumping:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yeIZpxOinRA